# I'm trying to use async/await to get a service, but the second service returns don't fill my variables

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service to get a list from server. But in this list I need to call another service to return the logo img, the service return ok, but my list remains empty. What i'm did wrong ?

I tried to use async/await in both services
I tried to use a separate function to get the logos later, but my html don't change.

```
 async getOpportunitiesByPage(_searchQueryAdvanced: any = 'active:true') {
    this.listaOportunidades = await this._opportunities
      .listaOportunidades(this.pageSize, this.currentPage, _searchQueryAdvanced)
      .toPromise()
      .then(result => {
        this.totalSize = result['totalElements'];
        return result['content'].map(async (opportunities: any) => {
          opportunities.logoDesktopUrl = await this.getBrand(opportunities['brandsUuid']);
          console.log(opportunities.logoDesktopUrl);
          return { opportunities };
        });
      });

    this.getTasks(this.totalSize);
  }
```

No errors, just my html don't change.
in my 
console.log(opportunities.logoDesktopUrl);
return undefined

but in the end return filled.

info:
Angular 7
server amazon aws.

Comment: Does `this.getBrand()` return a Promise?

Comment: No, a simple service 
```getBrand(brandsUuid) {
    this
      .brandService
      .getById(brandsUuid)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res.logoDesktopUrl);
          return res.logoDesktopUrl;
        });
  }```

Comment: [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) only waits on Promises. I would suggest looking at other Observable functions to do this, like maybe [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Answer (score 0):

`await` is used to wait for `promise`.

You should return `promise` from `getBrand` if you want to wait for it in `getOpportunitiesByPage`.

Change the `getBrand` function as following.

```
getBrand(brandsUuid): Observable<string> {
  this.brandService.getById(brandsUuid).pipe(map(res => { 
    console.log(res.logoDesktopUrl); return res.logoDesktopUrl;
  }))
}
```

Change `opportunities.logoDesktopUrl = await this.getBrand(opportunities['brandsUuid']);` to `opportunities.logoDesktopUrl = await this.getBrand(opportunities['brandsUuid']).toPromise();`

Please make sure you imported `map` from `rxjs/operators`.

Answer (score 0):

At first,when you `await`, you should not use `then`.

At second, `async/await` runs only with Promises.

```
async getOpportunitiesByPage(_searchQueryAdvanced: any = 'active:true') {
  const result = await this._opportunities
    .listaOportunidades(this.pageSize, this.currentPage, _searchQueryAdvanced)
    .toPromise();
  this.totalSize = result['totalElements'];
  this.listaOportunidades = result['content'].map(async (opportunities: any) => {
    opportunities.logoDesktopUrl = await this.getBrand(opportunities['brandsUuid']);
    console.log(opportunities.logoDesktopUrl);
    return opportunities;
  });

  this.getTasks(this.totalSize);
}

getBrand(brandsUuid) { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.brandService.getById(brandsUuid).subscribe(res => { 
      console.log(res.logoDesktopUrl);
      return resolve(res.logoDesktopUrl);
    }, err => {
      return reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

But, because `rxjs` is a used in Angular, you should use it instead of `async/await` :

```
getOpportunitiesByPage: void(_searchQueryAdanced: any = 'active:true') {
  this._opportunities.listaOportunidades(this.pageSize, this.currentPage, _searchQueryAdvanced).pipe(
    tap(result => {
      // we do that here because the original result will be "lost" after the next 'flatMap' operation
      this.totalSize = result['totalElements'];
    }),
    // first, we create an array of observables then flatten it with flatMap
    flatMap(result => result['content'].map(opportunities => this.getBrand(opportunities['brandsUuid']).pipe(
        // merge logoDesktopUrl into opportunities object
        map(logoDesktopUrl => ({...opportunities, ...{logoDesktopUrl}}))
      )
    ),
    // then we make each observable of flattened array complete
    mergeAll(),
    // then we wait for each observable to complete and push each result in an array
    toArray()
  ).subscribe(
    opportunitiesWithLogoUrl => { 
      this.listaOportunidades = opportunitiesWithLogoUrl;
      this.getTasks(this.totalSize);
    }, err => console.log(err)
  );
}

getBrand(brandsUuid): Observable<string> {
  return this.brandService.getById(brandsUuid).pipe(
    map(res => res.logoDesktopUrl)
  );
}
```

Here is a working example on [stackblittz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fhttbv)

There might be a simpler way to do it but it runs :-)